# How do I make a row in my DefaultModelTable get selected when I right click it to open a popupmenu

Tags: java, mouseevent, popupmenu, defaulttablemodel

I have made a DefaultTableModel with a popup menu, the issue is that when i right click to open the menu of the desired row, it openes the popup menu for the selected row. How can I make the rightclicked row get selected and then open the popup menu for that row?

Comment: Something like [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622973/jtable-copy-and-paste-using-clipboard-and-abstractaction/22623240#22623240)?

Comment: yes, but in my case Im not using a JTabke and the method addMouseListener doesnt exist and that´s what I´m struggling with. Can i convert my DefaultTableModel to a JTable?

Comment: A `JTable` is used to display a `DefaultTableModel` on the screen - sounds more like you need to spend some time [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to better understand how the system works - otherwise your questions make no sense

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a look. But for a quickfix, is it posible to use JTable methods on my DefaultTableModel object?

Comment: Short answer is - no,  `JTable` wraps `DefaultTableModel` - A table model has no concept of user interaction of it's own - which is why, without the `JTable`, you question makes no sense